# Access (.mdb) Database manipulation with jdbc

Tags: java, database, ms-access, jdbc, odbc

Background: Working on an application to be run on an Apache server hosted by Network Solutions.  Friend/Customer insisted on using an Access Database instead of SQL database.

Current Problem:  Wrote a Java test program to make sure I can connect to the database before I dive head first into writing the whole backend.  When I run this code on the JVM of the apache server the final product will be hosted:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class driverClass = Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            DriverManager.registerDriver((Driver) driverClass.newInstance());

            // set this to a MS Access DB you have on your machine
            String filename = new File(".").getCanonicalPath() + "/ITEMS.mdb";


            String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=";
            database+= filename.trim(); // add on to the end 
            // now we can get the connection from the DriverManager

            System.out.println(database);

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( database );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage() + " " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I get a null pointer exception on the line Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection( database)

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException

        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.initialize(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:436)

        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:153)

        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)

        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)

        at test.main(test.java:20)
```

To write this test I used this as my primary source: http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=2691&lngWId=2

Comment: MS-Access will only run on a Windows server.

Comment: MS-Access is also a "desktop" database - not a multi-user database. If you expose access to it to the web, you are in for a world of hurt. Do yourself a huge favor, and move all of the data to a real multi-user database, like Postgresql or MySql.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek While I agree with your sentiment, when someone else is paying the bills, if they want Access, they get Access, world of hurt and all.

Answer (score 0):

```
String strconnect="jdbc:odbc:DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb);DBQ="
Sring filename="some path";
StringBuilder a =new StringBuilder();
a.append(strconnect);
a.append(filename);
String db = a.toString();   
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection c= DriverManager.getrConnection(db,"","")
Statement stmt = c.createStament();
String query = "some query";
stmt.executeQuery(query);
c.close();
```

**Never get canonical Path, Either Specify the path of the access file or use JFile Explore and get path**

**also don't forget to close connection**

Comment: The explicit StringBuilder is unnecessary. `String db = strconnect + filename;` will automatically create a string builder for you. Makes it a lot cleaner. :)

Comment: you are right, but some cases include special charecters, so StringBuilder is safes way

Comment: Actually, they're identical. When you use the `+` or `+=` operator on a String in Java, the compiler puts a StringBuilder in the resulting bytecode. So whether you use the + opreator or not, you're using a StringBuilder.

Comment: Ok Man that fine, But is there any wrong using String builder.

Answer (score -1):

Since you mention apache, I will presume that the server is running Linux or BSD.
In that case, please have a look at the following:

- [Connecting to access database from linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742322/connecting-to-access-database-from-linux)
- Good [Linux ODBC drivers for Access](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-access-driver/getting-started.html) are expensive! (US$850 for a single machine!)

There is no default drivers for Access provided on linux, and the JDBC ODBC won't work unless you install one.

Unless there is a very special and *overwhelming good* reason for using an Access database as the backend to a website on a linux server, tell your friend that this is not technically or even economically coherent.

If you need a lightweight database on the server, use [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/): it's free, there is good support for [connecting to it from Java in linux](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-jdbc/), there is good tooling (even [browser plugins](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/)), and you can always [convert that database to Access](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ConverterTools) if your friend want to get an Access backup once in a while.

Otherwise, go for PostgreSQL or MySQL like everyone does (generally for a good reason).

Comment: I think it's a poor decision to assume that if you're running Apache, you're also running a Unix operation system. There are plenty of shops that run Windows and still run Apache.