# JDBC-ODBC drivers for Mac ,while reading MS -Excel files

Tags: java, macos, excel, jdbc

Reading MS-Excel file using JDBC-ODBC on windows-7 is working properly,On Mac machine getting below error due to unable to find the proper JDBC-ODBC drivers for Mac environment.

Error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
```

Please do the needful to make proper setup on Mac.

Comment: You have to install ODBC drivers for mac. Google it.

Comment: RaM, see if discussion on below pages help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709843/jdbc-odbc-driver-connection

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420653/odbc-connection-to-ms-access-on-ubuntu/13428683#13428683

Comment: thanks for all,I resolved this using Apache POI ,because I didn't find proper opensource Excel-Mac driver.